# Extracting Latitude and Longitude data from USB sensor (Python 3.4)

Tags: python-3.x, gps

I want to obtain Latitude and Longitude data from a USB GPS Sensor. 
I can access the output of the GPS using the following code.

```
import time, serial
port ='COM5'
ser = serial.Serial(port)
ser.baudrate = 4800
line = ser.readline()
line2 = line.decode('latin-1')
print(line2.find("$GPGGA") != -1) #true when Lat & Long is available
print(line)
```

Different data is returned when I rerun the code. However, when the returned information contains the prefix “$GPGGA” Latitude and Longitude information is present (see Screenshot).  [image]

What is the best way to just extract/parse the Latitude and Longitude data from the returned data?

I feel this should be dead simple, and I am missing something basic.

New to programing .
Thanks 
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get lat, orientation #1, long, orientation #2, when string is valid, just do:

```
if line2.startswith("$GPGGA"):
    lat,dir1,long,dir2 = line2.split(",")[2:6]
```

that will assign the 4 variables as the info youre looking for.